# Android XML Square Inside a Square

Tags: android, xml, android-animation, android-xml, android-drawable

I'm attempting to create an Android XML Drawable that looks like a square inside a square. Ideally the outer square would be twice the size of the inner square. For example, if the outer square was 4 units by 4 units (whatever those units are), the inner square would be 2 units by 2 units and centered inside the outer square.

At runtime I would like to change the color of the inner square from black to white with an animation that starts off with the inner white at a point in the center and have it grow to full size, 2 units by 2 units in the example. The outer square's color will be chosen by the user at runtime.

I would like to keep the required API level to a reasonable minimum, say API 19.

I've tried to use a Scale Drawable because it has a percentage (50% in my case) value, but it requires a "level" attribute that isn't available in XML, except in Java code or XML with a high API level. I also tried a Vector Drawable, but that doesn't allow me to choose the outer square's color forcing it to white no matter what is set. Using a Shape Drawable doesn't seem to allow the use of percentages, so I don't know how to make it half the size since I won't the actual size of the outer square until runtime.

I'm sure I could figure this out in pure Java with some work, but it seems like a simple enough request that XML should work. If there isn't an XML way, that would be good info too so I quit wasting my time looking.

thx

Comment: @pskink, thanks. Do you know how to do it without animation? I already got the animation part working in xml. Maybe I could figure it out if I could draw it without the animation.

Comment: If anyone else is trying this, I've given up and drawing the image myself in the onDraw. I can't see a way to do this otherwise.